Error message "UnboundLocalError: cannot access local variable 'player_points' where it is not associated with a value" in a while loop
I defined a variable named "player_points", that equals 0. When i use it in an if statement, the variable works, but when i use it in a while loop, the variable gives this error message: "UnboundLocalError: cannot access local variable 'player_points' where it is not associated with a value". I have tried to fix this, but i have no idea how to.
import random
def roll():
    min_roll = 1
    max_roll = 6
    amount = 0
    amount += random.randint(min_roll, max_roll)
    print(str(amount))
    return amount

player_points = 0

terminal_points = 0

def gameContinuation():
    gameContinueLoop = input("Do you want to roll? yes or no ")
    if gameContinueLoop == "yes":
        while player_points < 51:
            player_points += roll()

this is part of my code, and i am getting the error message from the while loop at the bottom.

Put global player_points at the top of the function.  Otherwise it thinks player_points is a local variable.

The difference between an if-statement an a while-loop is a red herring, especially since any while <condition> can be rewritten as while True: if <condition>: break.

It's not clear what exactly this code is supposed to do, for example if you access player_points as a global, then if you re-ran gameContinuation, the while-loop would immediately exit. Is that what you want? If not, maybe you want to move player_points = 0 into the function? I've linked an existing question that gives an overview of this error so you can decide for yourself. There might be other ways to change this code too that I haven't thought of. BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour] and [ask] for tips, like making a [mre] including example input and desired output.

Also, beside the point, but print(str(...)) is redundant since print() converts its arguments to str automatically. And amount = 0; amount += ... is not necessary when you can just write amount = ....
